# Pause between gganimate loops

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, gganimate

Is it possible to add a pause between gganimate loops? I know we can set the interval between frames with `interval`, but is there a way to pause on the final frame before looping back to the first frame?

Is the best method to insert multiple copies of the final frame into the data?

Comment: Did you reach a solution? I'm going with your suggested workaround for now

Answer (score 17):

In recent versions of **gganimate**, the `animate()` function has an `end_pause` option. So you can simply do

`animate(p, end_pause = 30)`

in order to pause for, for example, 30 frames before looping again.

Answer (score 10):

It's possible by adjusting the `render` option in `animate`. Using an example from the README,

```
p <- ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp)) + 
  geom_line(size = 2, colour = 'steelblue') + 
  transition_states(Month, 4, 1) + 
  shadow_mark(size = 1, colour = 'grey')
animate(p, renderer = gifski_renderer(loop = F))
```

Note that this prevents the animation from looping, as opposed to adding a pause between loops. To add a pause between loops, this link should help, as suggested in the answer by Alan:

[Any way to pause at specific frames/time points with transition_reveal in gganimate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092216/any-way-to-pause-at-specific-frames-time-points-with-transition-reveal-in-gganim)

Answer (score 0):

A working solution has been provided in another post:

[Any way to pause at specific frames/time points with transition_reveal in gganimate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092216/any-way-to-pause-at-specific-frames-time-points-with-transition-reveal-in-gganim)

```
airq_pause <- airq %>%
  mutate(show_time = case_when(Day %in% c(10,20,31) ~ 10,
                               TRUE                 ~ 1)) %>%
  # uncount is a tidyr function which copies each line 'n' times
  uncount(show_time) %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  mutate(reveal_time = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Just edit the following line of code:

```
mutate(show_time = case_when(Day %in% c(10,20,31) ~ 10,
                                 TRUE             ~ 1),
```

to something along the lines of:

```
mutate(show_time = case_when(Day %in% max(Day) ~ 10,
                                 TRUE          ~ 1),
```

and adjust/remove the group_by() call accordingly.  It may be necessary to change the ~10 to a higher number to see the pause.