# Is is it possible to add an end pause when using SaveGif from the {animate} R package?

Tags: r

I am creating a GIF using the SaveGif function from the [animate](https://yihui.org/animation/) package, and want to add an end pause to the gif.(i.e. The GIF pauses X number of frames/seconds before repeating itself). Is this possible? I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation, but if there is some way to implement this, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092216/any-way-to-pause-at-specific-frames-time-points-with-transition-reveal-in-gganim

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.