# Getting Invalid input type, expected 'double' actual 'logical' error in gganimate

Tags: r, gganimate, rmaps

While replicating a question posed [on this website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923904/how-to-make-the-transition-time-between-2-frames-longer-in-gganimate), I tried to rerun the following code

```
data <- structure(list(x = 1:6, y = 2:7, year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 
                                          2011L, 2012L, 2012L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                     -6L))

library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point() +
  transition_time(year) +
  labs(title = "Year: {as.integer(frame_time)}")

p_anim <- animate(p, nframes = 30, fps = 4)
anim_save("myfig.gif", p_anim)
```

While it was supposed to work fine, I received the following error, which I am usually getting in making animated visualizations with `gganimate` such as replicating the animated map [in this post](https://rpubs.com/haleyepperlyfox/919270)

`Invalid input type, expected 'double' actual 'logical'`.

I do not understand why this error occurs, and I could not find any similar posts on the web except this post, which is [unanswered](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/448). Therefore, I welcome your replies regarding this error. Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to replicate your error:

[image]

I'd suggest checking your R and package versions (e.g. with `sessionInfo()`) and make sure they're all up-to-date.

Output of your code + my sessionInfo():

```
> data <- structure(list(x = 1:6, y = 2:7, year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 
+                                                   2011L, 2012L, 2012L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
+                                                                                                              -6L))
> library(tidyverse)
── Attaching packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.1 ──
✔ ggplot2 3.3.6     ✔ purrr   0.3.4
✔ tibble  3.1.7     ✔ dplyr   1.0.9
✔ tidyr   1.2.0     ✔ stringr 1.4.0
✔ readr   2.1.2     ✔ forcats 0.5.1
── Conflicts ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
> library(gganimate)
> p <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y))+
+   geom_point() +
+   transition_time(year) +
+   labs(title = "Year: {as.integer(frame_time)}")
> p_anim <- animate(p, nframes = 30, fps = 4)
                                                                                                                                                   
Inserting image 30 at 7.25s (100%)...
Encoding to gif... done!
> anim_save("myfig.gif", p_anim)
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.3.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.1/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] gganimate_1.0.7 forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.9     purrr_0.3.4     readr_2.1.2     tidyr_1.2.0     tibble_3.1.7    ggplot2_3.3.6  
[10] tidyverse_1.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] progress_1.2.2    tidyselect_1.1.2  haven_2.5.0       colorspace_2.0-3  vctrs_0.4.1       generics_0.1.2    utf8_1.2.2        rlang_1.0.3      
 [9] pillar_1.7.0      glue_1.6.2        withr_2.5.0       DBI_1.1.3         tweenr_1.0.2      dbplyr_2.2.1      modelr_0.1.8      readxl_1.4.0     
[17] lifecycle_1.0.1   plyr_1.8.7        munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.3.0      cellranger_1.1.0  rvest_1.0.2       labeling_0.4.2    tzdb_0.3.0       
[25] fansi_1.0.3       gifski_1.6.6-1    broom_1.0.0       Rcpp_1.0.8.3      scales_1.2.0      backports_1.4.1   jsonlite_1.8.0    farver_2.1.0     
[33] fs_1.5.2          digest_0.6.29     hms_1.1.1         stringi_1.7.6     grid_4.2.1        cli_3.3.0         tools_4.2.1       magrittr_2.0.3   
[41] crayon_1.5.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.2    xml2_1.3.3        prettyunits_1.1.1 reprex_2.0.1      lubridate_1.8.0   assertthat_0.2.1 
[49] httr_1.4.3        rstudioapi_0.13   R6_2.5.1          compiler_4.2.1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As you suggested, I guess the problem was most probably due to the version of R Studio I was using while making the animated map (my old version was 4.1.2 if I am not wrong). When I updated R Studio, the code run but I had to add `renderer = gifski_renderer()` inside `animate` function since it primarily gave an error saying that `The animation object does not specify a save_animation method`, which I am not sure why it happened so. Nonetheless, I was able to finally replicate the code. Therefore, thank you for your help.